# Match country code and phone number validation using regex in Laravel

Tags: php, regex, laravel, laravel-5.4

I'm trying to validate an phone number using regex. Basically, i don't know more about regex :) I want to validate it with country code and only numeric value Like: `+1-1234567891`

I'm using below code to make validation:

```
'phone_no' => 'required|regex:/^([0-9\s\-\+\(\)]*)$/',
```

But it's not working for country code, but it's work for only numeric value.

Can anyone have an idea how to make this validation without creating custom validation?

Many thanks!!

Comment: put some example for valid and invalid country codes

Comment: @smart-googler: I already provide example in question. `+1-1234567891` Have you see that?

Comment: /^[0-9]{12,12}$/

Comment: @SachinAghera: Not worked. If i didn't pass country code `+91-` and pass `123657896` then it accpeted!

Comment: @hiren check updated

Comment: @SachinAghera: it's work if don't pass `+91-` but after passing `+91-` it also not accept!!

Comment: @SachinAghera: I created it using online tool. This is worked for me: `/^\+[1-9]{1,3}[\-][0-9]{3,14}$/` Anyway thanks for your time and help!!

Comment: @HirenGohel good...please also post the link of tool so it help for someone.

Comment: @SachinAghera: I used this link to generate regex: https://www.regextester.com/